# Getting description content on load in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Currently when replying to an e-mail the description content is loaded before my JavaScript runs.

Is there a way to wait for the description to load, before JavaScript code is executed?

My code:

```
function test() {
var desc = xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").getValue();
alert(desc); //Nothing, since description loads after I get the value
}
```

I added this function to the on load event of my form.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [blog post](http://nishantrana.me/2009/08/25/email-description-field-body-field-and-javascript-in-crm/) you have to wait for the description to load fully. Just in the same way you have to wait for a subgrid to load before accessing it.

Comment: That's actually quite interesting.
I solved my problem by waiting for the description to load, but not in that way, though.

I ended up checking if the description is empty, and if it is, set a timer that reruns the function until description contains content.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by checking if description is empty, and if it is, rerun the function.

```
function test() {
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").getValue() == "") {
        console.log("Description empty, rerunning in 1 second");
        setTimeout(function() {
            test();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the email for some reason is empty? then your javascript would continiously run utself

Comment: Hi,
It never is empty, since CRM adds <div></div> to description when it's loaded.